# How to print kernel stack's lower and upper address in linux for process using pid and without using pid

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How to print kernel stack's lower and upper address in linux for each process process

1. using pid and
2. without using pid

Answer (score 0):

You may want to understand into the [`current_stack_pointer()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L25) code. (for the slightly older kernels, now the stack size has been increased to 16K)

The kernel stack starts on top of the page and increases downwards, `%esp` on x86 points (or %rsp on x86_64) to the bottom of stack. You can also derive the current macro as follows

```
current macro == current_thread_info(%esp)->task
current->pid == (current_thread_info(%esp)->task)->pid
```

As you know the bottom of the stack, you need to add/subtract the number of pages to get the top of the kernel stack (using %esp or %rsp depends on your arch).